# invalid operands to binary "|"

Tags: c

While I am reading the FreeBSD source code about the `hlist` in the file `list.h`, I am confused about this macro:

```
#define hlist_for_each_entry_safe(tp, p, n, head, field)        \
for (p = (head)->first; p ?                 \
    (n = p->next) | (tp = hlist_entry(p, typeof(*tp), field)) : \
    NULL; p = n)
```

and I am trying use the similar style in my function as below:

```
int *a;
int *b;
int *c;

if(a ? (b = (int *)0x0c) | (c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)) : NULL){

    printf("test\n");
}
```

when I use GCC compile it, the compiler give me the error, says:

```
invalid operands to binary "|"
```

I write my function in that way, because I think the condition of the "for" circulation returns "true" or "false", but in fact the compiler seems to tell me they are not the same.And then I do not understand the condition between "for" and "if".

PS:My mother tongue is not English, maybe you could not understand it well, I am sorry about that.

Comment: Can you show the line where you use it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about `n` and `tp`?  Specifically, what are their intended types?  Alternately, is the `hlist_for_each_entry_safe()` macro actually invoked somewhere in the code?  If so, how, exactly?

Comment: That is a recipe for disaster. Works or not for someone else - please please please don't do this to yourself and whoever else to ever work with your code.

Comment: @CarlNorum I have updated the content as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `|` with pointers.  You have to use an integral type.  I don't know about the FreeBSD code you cite, but they may use `uintptr_t`.

Regardless, `littleadv` is right.  Don't ever do this.  It is unreadable and unmaintainable gobbledygook.

Comment: I think it is a written mistaken about "|", maybe they want it "||"

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some funky code - the `|` operator only works on integers, but that code looks like it's intending to operate on pointers.  I'm just guessing about the semantics based on the `->next`, but if that's a pointer field, this code isn't going to work, as you've seen.